# Removing a single bulleted icon from a bootstrap list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-element

I have a Bootstrap list-group that I've bulleted with icons. I'm trying to remove the very-first icon from the list-group. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="vacationList">
              <li class="list-group-item text-center" id="vacationListTitle">Our in-home pet care includes the following care treatment:</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">All the love, attention, kissing and scracthing your pet deserves</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Walk, exercise, playtime or visit</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Food, treats and fresh water as needed</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Trash and pet waste removal</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">The administration of medicine</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Gathering of of all mail</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Watering of all plants and garden</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Report card including the time of the visit and details of the pet care experience</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">In additional we are prepared to accomodate any other unlisted and reasonable needs</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">$65 includes overnight stay from 8:00 pm until 7:00 am and 1 late afternoon visit. Includes care for 2 pets ($3 per additional pet)</li>
            </ul>
```

```css
#vacationListTitle {
  background-color:map-get($colorMap, orangeColor) !important;
  font-family:$headerFont;
  font-size:1.3em;
  content:none !important;
  padding-left:0px !important;
}

#vacationList {
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius:5px;

  li {
    padding-left:30px;
  }

  li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
  }

  li:before {
    /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as the bullet point*/
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -21px;
    color: #555;
  }
}
```

The list item with the class name vacationListTitle is the one I wish to delete the icon from. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: `#vacationListTitle:before { display: none; }` ?

Comment: Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `display` property, targetting the `::before` pseudo-element specifically:

```css
#vacationListTitle::before {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This markup makes that list item disappear. I just want icon to disappear.

Comment: @Brixsta ah sorry, I missed that part of your question. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the content of the first before li of the **vacationList**

```
#vacationList {
    .....
    .....
    .....
    li:first-of-type:before {
      content: "";
    }
}
```

Or you can use the id **#vacationListTitle** directly

```
 #vacationListTitle:before {
      content: "";
    }
```

[**See demo here**](http://www.bootply.com/7uTvpTBJDS)

Comment: This won't work because it has lower specificity than the selector which adds the icon in OP's example.